# how to implement auto authentication between communities with custom domain?

Tags: community, oauth2, customer-community, single-sign-on, authentication

I have created two communities with custom domain in same org.
Two communities are myold1.test.com(VF template) and mynew1.test.com(Customer service template).
As an external user whenever I launch myold1 community from mynew1 community then I should be landed in myold1 and vice versa without additional authentication .
I have tried the same thing in Sandbox and Personal org, it's working fine as those using default force.com domain. But in my production org it's not working.
I have added an users and profiles in both the communities so I have no issues in logging in each communities separately. But when it comes to launchimg one from another then I'm not able to do.
Fingers crossed.!!!!
Can anyone suggest what needs to be implemented for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done the setup like below and I'm able to switch between communities.

1. Created new SSO in Salesforce org.(setup > Single sign-on)
2. Created new connected app for the new SSO in the same org.(setup > app manager) and added the profiles under profile based access section.
3. Created a new remote site for the SSO issuer URL(new custom domain) under setup > remote site settings.
4. In old community > Workspace > login & registration, selected default page as login page and enabled the new SSO as the only option. Deselected the rest.
   So now whenever I launch old community from new community, the SSO will take care of my authentication. Its working like charm.:)

Note: I have enabled only SAML  and not OAuth setting in the new connnected app.